# Show only lebels of those percentage in piechart which is greater than 5% in Chart JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts

I am learning web dev and chart js, and working with pie chart. my chart looks like below; As we can see smaller percentage value is not at all visible and is making our website bad. how can we eliminate smaller percentage. I am attaching my work how I got below pie chart. kinly looking for help. Thanks.

**Edit: By showing a percentage greater than 5% I meant, the percentage value to be written only on area greater than 5%. data with less than 5% should also be present in pie chart, but don't show the percentage labels.**

```html
 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
     -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@0.7.0"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <canvas id="myChart1" width="90" height="90" style="width:100%;max-width:650px"></canvas>
  <script>
        function getColors(length) {
        let pallet = ["#0074D9", "#FF4136", "#2ECC40", "#FF851B", "#7FDBFF", "#B10DC9", "#FFDC00", "#001f3f", "#39CCCC", "#01FF70", "#85144b", "#F012BE", "#3D9970", "#111111", "#AAAAAA"];
        let colors = [];
  
        for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          colors.push(pallet[i % (pallet.length - 1)]);
        }
  
        return colors;
      }
      var xValues = ['Multimeter', 'UniBox', 'Toby', 'Cables', 'Test','nokia','samsung','Jio','honda'];
      var yValues = [2, 100, 223, 84, 197,3,8,7,50];
      var barColors = getColors(xValues.length);
      var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart1").getContext('2d');
     var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
     type: 'pie',
     data: {
      labels: xValues,
      datasets: [{
        backgroundColor: barColors,
        data: yValues
      }]
     },
    options:{
      tooltips: {
        enabled: true
      },
      plugins: {
        datalabels: {
          formatter: (value, ctx) => {
    
            let sum = ctx.dataset._meta[0].total;
            let percentage = (value * 100 / sum).toFixed(2) + "%";
            return percentage;
    
    
          },
          color: '#fff',
        }
      },
      "legend": {
        "display": true,
        "labels": {
          "fontSize": 20,
        }
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        fontColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
        fontSize: 25,
        text: "Current Inventory Received"
      }
    }
  });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to change the formatter function , it should return a value only if the percentage is greater than 5

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
     -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@0.7.0"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <canvas id="myChart1" width="90" height="90" style="width:100%;max-width:650px"></canvas>
  <script>
        function getColors(length) {
        let pallet = ["#0074D9", "#FF4136", "#2ECC40", "#FF851B", "#7FDBFF", "#B10DC9", "#FFDC00", "#001f3f", "#39CCCC", "#01FF70", "#85144b", "#F012BE", "#3D9970", "#111111", "#AAAAAA"];
        let colors = [];
  
        for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          colors.push(pallet[i % (pallet.length - 1)]);
        }
  
        return colors;
      }
      var xValues = ['Multimeter', 'UniBox', 'Toby', 'Cables', 'Test','nokia','samsung','Jio','honda'];
      var yValues = [2, 100, 223, 84, 197,3,8,7,50];
   
      var barColors = getColors(xValues.length);
      var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart1").getContext('2d');
     var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
     type: 'pie',
     data: {
      labels: xValues,
      datasets: [{
        backgroundColor: barColors,
        data: yValues
      }]
     },
    options:{
      tooltips: {
        enabled: true
      },
      plugins: {
        datalabels: {
          formatter: (value, ctx) => {
    
            let sum = ctx.dataset._meta[0].total;
            let percentage = (value * 100 / sum).toFixed(2);
            return percentage > 5 ? percentage + "%" : "" ;
    
    
          },
          color: '#fff',
        }
      },
      "legend": {
        "display": true,
        "labels": {
          "fontSize": 20,
        }
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        fontColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
        fontSize: 25,
        text: "Current Inventory Received"
      }
    }
  });
  
 
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it removes smaller percentage data. By showing a percentage greater than 5% I meant, the percentage value to be written only on area greater than 5%. data with less than 5% should also be present in pie chart, but don't show the percentage labels.

Comment: for that you can change the formatter to 
          formatter: (value, ctx) => {
    
         
            let sum = ctx.dataset._meta[0].total;
           console.log(sum , 'sums' , value)
           let percentage = (value * 100 / sum).toFixed(2) 
           console.log(percentage)
            return percentage ? percentage + "%" : ""
    
    
          }

Comment: do i have to change my answer ?

Comment: i will request you sir, it will be of huge help.

Comment: changed my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246194/discussion-between-def-init-and-faizal-hussain).

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the sum using the `reduce` method and then use `filter` to check if percentage is greater than 5. You can pass the `result` array to the chart.

```
let yValues = [2, 100, 223, 84, 197,3,8,7,50];
let sum = yValues.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item, 0)
let result = yValues.filter(value => {
    let percentage = ( value / sum ) * 100;
    if ( percentage > 5 ) return true;
    else false;
})
```